# Why My jQuery Function always Executed in Conditional?

Tags: jquery, function, conditional-statements

I intend to put my function executed in a conditional statement. If the statement is true, the function should be executed and vise versa.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.validateName = function(){
    return true;
  }

  $('input[name=name]').blur(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a.length == 0)
    {
       $('#alert_name').fadeIn();
    }
    else 
    {
       $('#alert_name').hide();
       $(this).validateName();
    }     
  })
})
```

The validateName function is only to return true value, so when the input value is more than 0, it should have 'true' value in return. But in my case, no matter condition is, the function always being executed and returns 'true' value.

Please tell me where the problem is. Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually sure that control enters `validateName` function? `return true` there really does nothing as this `boolean` value is not being "received" in `else` branch.

Comment: You should do a `return $(this).validateName()` otherwise the `return true` would have no effect

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything from your blur function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.validateName = function() {
        return true;
    }

    $('input[name=name]').blur(function() {
        var a = $(this).val();
        if (a.length === 0) {
            $('#alert_name').fadeIn();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#alert_name').hide();
            return $(this).validateName();
        }
    })
})​
```